# How to map and collect primitive return type using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, byte, java-stream

I am new in Java 8 streams and I am wondering if there is way to perform `forEach/map` call on method returning a `byte` and accepting an `int` as parameter.

Example:

```
public class Test {
   private byte[] byteArray; // example of byte array

   public byte getByte(int index) {
      return this.byteArray[index];
   }

   public byte[] getBytes(int... indexes) {
      return Stream.of(indexes)
             .map(this::getByte) // should return byte
             .collect(byte[]::new); // should return byte[]
   }
}
```

As you may guess, the `getBytes` method not working. `"int[] cannot be converted to int"`Probably somewhere is missing foreach, but personally cant figure it out.

However, this is working, old-fashioned approach which I would like to rewrite as Stream.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[indexes.length];
for ( int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++ ) {
   byteArray[i] = this.getByte( indexes[i] );
}
return byteArray;
```

Comment: Nope. There is no `ByteStream`. But due to word alignment, a `byte` isn't likely to be 8 bits anyway. Your loop based approach is simple, clear and idiomatic - why do you want to change it?

Comment: Thank you for answer. That is probably reason why I was unable to make it work. However, isn't there a way to do it anyway? Using type cast or or writing my own ByteStream?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own `Collector` and build your `byte[]` with an `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
final class MyCollectors {

  private MyCollectors() {}

  public static Collector<Byte, ?, byte[]> toByteArray() {
    return Collector.of(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, ByteArrayOutputStream::write, (baos1, baos2) -> {
      try {
        baos2.writeTo(baos1);
        return baos1;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
      }
    }, ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray);
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
public byte[] getBytes(int... indexes) {
  return IntStream.of(indexes).mapToObj(this::getByte).collect(MyCollectors.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are open to using a third-party library, [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has collections support for all eight Java primitive types.  The following should work:

```
public byte[] getBytes(int... indexes) {
    return IntLists.mutable.with(indexes)
            .asLazy()
            .collectByte(this::getByte)
            .toArray();
}
```

Updated: I changed the original code to be lazy.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 4):

There's no good way to do this with streams. Any implementation using `collect` is going to rely on appending elements, which gets really ugly for arrays. This is as close as you're going to get:

```
int[] ints = IntStream.of(indexes)
        .map(this::getByte) // upcast to int, still IntStream
        .toArray(); // specialized collect
```

The `IntStream.toArray` method has a ton of overhead involving internal "node" objects and array concatenation, so this is also much less efficient. I recommend sticking with the old `for` loop.

Comment: Thank for answer and explanation. It was just an example but I guess I will stick with for loops.